# Design Time Extension Properties In Winforms

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, design-time

I have built out a couple of keyboards for a touch aware app we are building in work. Since we use a controller that is aware of when the app is in touch screen mode I thought it would be nice if, in design mode, we could associate a control with a keyboard type and have the controller look after the calling of the keyboard.

One of the things I do not want to do is to sub class each type of control just to add this property as I feel it is a very heavy for small gain. I had thought of using the tag property but it is not available in all controls due to use.

I was wondering if there is a way of attaching a property to a control on design time for the purpose of adding this meta data. So to recap I would like to be able to give each control a value that would be read by the controller to decide what keyboard to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the designer supports this.  Good examples of existing components that do this are ErrorProvider and HelpProvider.  Note how they add properties to existing control types.

You'll want to implement your own component, it needs to implement the IExtenderProvider interface.  The [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider.aspx) for it has a good example that should help you getting it right.

Comment: Thanks for the link and explanation!